# Linux mounted VFAT filesystem shows semicolon-asciicode for some uppercase letters

Tags: linux, filesystems, vfat

The disk is listed as follows:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 298.09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: USB 2.5"-HDD    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4f...

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1          63 625137344 625137282 298.1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

When I mount it to `/mnt/disk`, it gets mounted as

```
/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/disk type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

The problem that I have is, that for some of the files and directories I have something that looks like a *corrupted* filename. For example instead of what I would expect to be `VirtualBox VMs`, I see `;086irtual;066ox ;086;077s`. It doesn't happen on *all* capital letters, there are paths where it works properly deep down into subdirectories.

A filesystem check throws an error, but I'm not sure that is a critical one or related:

```
$ sudo fsck.vfat /dev/sdd
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Logical sector size (64543 bytes) is not a multiple of the physical sector size.
```

FWIW, the USB drive is quite old (10-15 years) and hasn't been used in a while. I wouldn't be surprised if it's somehow corrupted.

My question is: How can I fix this? I want to have filenames/paths without the semicolon encoding. I could write a script to decode it, but maybe there's some underlying filesystem effect at play here.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to re-format the disk.

Comment: Could you try mounting with `iocharset=utf8` instead?